# Python: replace a pattern in a df column with another pattern

Tags: python, pandas, regex

I have a dataframe as per the below:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame(
     columns=['deal','details'],
     data=[
           ['deal1', 'MH92h'],
           ['deal2', 'L97h'],
           ['deal3', '97.538'],
           ['deal4', 'LM98h'],
           ['deal5', 'TRD (97.612 cvr)'],
          ]
                 )
```

I would like to replace the any row that has `details` = `MH[0-9]h` with `[0-9].75`
For example, the output would look as follows:

```
df =
['deal1', 'MH92h', '92.75']
['deal2', 'L97h', 'L97h'],
['deal3', '97.538', '97.538'],
['deal4', 'MH98h', '98.75'],
['deal5', 'TRD 97.61', 'TRD 97.61']
```

I've tried the below, but it doesn't work:

```
df = df.assign(test_col=df.details.str.replace("\d+",r'\d+'+'75'), regex=True)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could match `MH([0-9]+)h` and replace with capture group 1.

See the capture group 1 at this [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/Z4JEYR/1).

Note that deal4 has `LM98h` and not `MH98h`

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame(
    columns=['deal','details'],
    data=[
        ['deal1', 'MH92h'],
        ['deal2', 'L97h'],
        ['deal3', '97.538'],
        ['deal4', 'LM98h'],
        ['deal5', 'TRD (97.612 cvr)'],
    ]
)

df = df.assign(test_col=df.details.str.replace(r"MH([0-9]+)h", "\g<1>.75"))
print(df)
```

print(df)

Output

```
    deal           details          test_col
0  deal1             MH92h             92.75
1  deal2              L97h              L97h
2  deal3            97.538            97.538
3  deal4             LM98h             LM98h
4  deal5  TRD (97.612 cvr)  TRD (97.612 cvr)
```

Comment: Thank you, that works! Would you mind pointing me to where I can find the documentation on `why` that works? I couldn't work out how to sub back in the original pattern! Thank you again :)

Comment: @Mike You are welcome, this is the [replace](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.replace.html) function which takes a regex as the first parameter, and the replacement as the second parameter. The regex `MH([0-9]+)h` has a capture group for the digits, which you can refer to in the replacement with `\g<1>`

Comment: Oh, great. I didn't know about the `\g<1>`. Would you mind pointing me to some documentation on this? I've read this https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html, but it doesn't mention the above trick. Thanks again

Comment: @Mike That documentation is here https://docs.python.org/3/howto/regex.html

Comment: Great, thank you! I do actually have one follow up: I've noted that the above, when it doesn't find a match, still copies across the details column (I guess because it's a replace). Is there any way to do it such that only affects rows where it has matches, and ignores other rows?

Comment: @Mike That is indeed the effect of the replace function. If you want another value for the non matched values, perhaps like this https://onecompiler.com/python/3yzvb2b57

Comment: I'll have a look, thank you again for your help!